# Determine proportion of cheating students using MCMC implemented in Turing.jl

Tags: julia, mcmc

I am trying to solve the following problem using Julia:

Determine the frequency of students cheating during an exam. If we let N be the total number of students who took the exam, and assuming each student is interviewed post-exam using the following privacy retaining algorithm:

"In the interview process for each student, the student flips a coin, hidden from the interviewer. The student agrees to answer honestly if the coin comes up heads. Otherwise, if the coin comes up tails, the student (secretly) flips the coin again, and answers “Yes, I did cheat” if the coin flip lands heads, and “No, I did not cheat”, if the coin flip lands tails. This way, the interviewer does not know if a “Yes” was the result of a guilty plea, or a Heads on a second coin toss. Thus privacy is preserved and the researchers receive honest answers."

I have written the following code to determine the posterior distribution of cheating students:

```
const N = 100
const YES_ANSWERS = 35

const SAMPLES = 1000000
using DataStructures
using Distributions

function simulate(N, YES_ANSWERS, SAMPLES)
    d = DefaultDict{Int64, Int64}(0) 
    for i in 1:SAMPLES
        cheating = rand(0:N)
        not_cheating = N - cheating
        
        cheating_honest_yes = rand(Binomial(cheating, 0.5))
        cheating_second_toss = cheating - cheating_honest_yes
        cheating_random_yes = rand(Binomial(cheating_second_toss, 0.5))
        cheating_yes_answers = cheating_honest_yes + cheating_random_yes
        
        not_cheating_second_toss = rand(Binomial(not_cheating, 0.5))
        not_cheating_random_yes = rand(Binomial(not_cheating_second_toss, 0.5))
        
        total_yes = cheating_yes_answers + not_cheating_random_yes
        if total_yes == YES_ANSWERS
            d[cheating] += 1
        end
    end
    
    d
end

const N = 100
const YES_ANSWERS = 35
const SAMPLES = 1000000

d = simulate(N, YES_ANSWERS, SAMPLES)

using Plots
cheaters = [k/N for k in keys(d)]
probability = [v/sum(values(d)) for v in values(d)]
g = scatter(cheaters, probability)
gui(g)
```

Essentially I draw and count and calculate the probabilities

I then tried to use Turing.jl but got stuck:

```
using DataStructures
using Distributions
using Turing

@model function CheatingDistribution(N)
    cheating ~ DiscreteUniform(0, N)
    not_cheating = N - cheating
    
    cheating_honest_yes ~ Binomial(cheating, 0.5)
    cheating_second_toss = cheating - cheating_honest_yes
    cheating_random_yes ~ Binomial(cheating_second_toss, 0.5)
    cheating_yes_answers = cheating_honest_yes + cheating_random_yes
    
    not_cheating_second_toss ~ Binomial(not_cheating, 0.5)
    not_cheating_random_yes ~ Binomial(not_cheating_second_toss, 0.5)
    
    total_yes = cheating_yes_answers + not_cheating_random_yes
    total_yes       
end
```

I cannot infer `cheating` from `total_yes`.

That said, I could use this model to reproduce the results that I got with the previous code:

```
using DataStructures
using Distributions
using Turing

@model function CheatingDistribution(N)
    cheating ~ DiscreteUniform(0, N)
    not_cheating = N - cheating
    
    cheating_honest_yes ~ Binomial(cheating, 0.5)
    cheating_second_toss = cheating - cheating_honest_yes
    cheating_random_yes ~ Binomial(cheating_second_toss, 0.5)
    cheating_yes_answers = cheating_honest_yes + cheating_random_yes
    
    not_cheating_second_toss ~ Binomial(not_cheating, 0.5)
    not_cheating_random_yes ~ Binomial(not_cheating_second_toss, 0.5)
    
    total_yes = cheating_yes_answers + not_cheating_random_yes
    total_yes       
end

function simulate(N, actual_yes_answers, n_samples)
    d = DefaultDict{Int64, Int64}(0) 
    cheatDist = CheatingDistribution(N)
    for _ in 1:n_samples
        result = rand(cheatDist)
        
        total_yes = result.cheating_honest_yes + result.cheating_random_yes + result.not_cheating_random_yes
        if total_yes == actual_yes_answers
            d[result.cheating] += 1
        end
    end
    
    cheaters = [k/N for k in keys(d)]
    probability = [v/sum(values(d)) for v in values(d)]
    return cheaters, probability
end

const N = 100           # Number of students
const YES_ANSWERS = 35  # Number of students that answered yes (both cheating and honest students)
const SAMPLES = 1000000

cheaters, probability = simulate(N, YES_ANSWERS, SAMPLES)

using Plots
g = scatter(cheaters, probability)
gui(g)
```

I then wrote a new version where I sum up the probabilities and get the same result except that it is more accurate, especially when yes answers in interviews are low. For example 3 students answered yes I cheated. The following is the code using probabilities:

```
using DataStructures
using Distributions

function simulate(N, YES_ANSWERS)
    d = DefaultOrderedDict{Int64, Float64}(0) 
    for cheating in 0:N
        p1 = 1.0 / N
        not_cheating = N - cheating
        
        for cheating_honest_yes in 0:cheating
            p2 = p1 * pdf(Binomial(cheating, 0.5), cheating_honest_yes)
            cheating_second_toss = cheating - cheating_honest_yes
            for cheating_random_yes in 0:cheating_second_toss
                p3 = p2 * pdf(Binomial(cheating_second_toss, 0.5), cheating_random_yes)
                cheating_yes_answers = cheating_honest_yes + cheating_random_yes
                
                for not_cheating_second_toss in 0:not_cheating
                    p4 = p3 * pdf(Binomial(not_cheating, 0.5), not_cheating_second_toss)
                    for not_cheating_random_yes in 0:not_cheating_second_toss
                        p5 = p4 * pdf(Binomial(not_cheating_second_toss, 0.5), not_cheating_random_yes)
                        
                        total_yes = cheating_yes_answers + not_cheating_random_yes
                        
                        if total_yes == YES_ANSWERS
                            d[cheating] += p5
                        end
                    end
                end
            end
        end
    end
    d
end

const N = 100
const YES_ANSWERS = 35

d = simulate(N, YES_ANSWERS)

using Plots
cheaters = [k/N for k in keys(d)]
probability = [v/sum(values(d)) for v in values(d)]
g = bar(cheaters, probability)
gui(g)
```

I got this toy problem from the book "Baysian Methods for Hackers". The following is how the solution look like:

[image: Solution from the book]

Note that the bin size in the solution is 10 while I am showing the PMF. So I am showing densities one tenth of the solution above.

My question: How do I solve this problem using MCMCChain.jl?

Comment: What exactly doesn't work with the Turing model? Do you just get a different posterior, or what? It would be helpful if you included the construction of the model and the `sample` call and output.

Comment: Ah, wait, the problem is how to condition on `total_yes`, right?

Comment: @phipsgabler Yes indeed. In fact I am looking for a general solution for this type of problem that does not involve doing the math (which would defeat the purpose of using numerical solutions).